# The uniqueness of Kerr-Schild form

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems

The Kerr-Schild form is defined as
$$g_{ab}=\eta_{ab}+Sk_ak_b,$$
where $k_a$ is the null vector measured by both $g_{ab}$ and $\eta_{ab}$.
The Kerr-Schild form of the Schwarzschild metric is always written as
$$  d s^{2}= -dt'^{2}-d r^2+r^{2}\left(d \theta^{2}+\sin ^{2} \theta d \phi^{2}\right) +\frac{2M}{r}  (dt'^2-2dt'dr+dr^2).$$
However, it could be seen that the Schwarzschild metric in the Eddington-Finkelstein coordinate also exhibits the Kerr-Schild structure:
$$d s^{2}= -du^{2}-2 d ud r+r^{2}\left(d \theta^{2}+\sin ^{2} \theta d \phi^{2}\right) +\frac{2M}{r}  du^{2}.$$
The $u$ and $t'$ are linked by $u=t'+r$.

Moreover, as a coordinate will not mix the $\eta_{ab}$ and $k_ak_b$ term, it is possible to write the metric in Kerr-Schild form but with a different coordinate.

My question is, is there any particular reason most people use the first coordinate? Or the Kerr-Schild form in different coordinates are totally equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are equivalent. In the [first](http://yukterez.net/f/einstein.equations/files/59.html#1) form the ingoing and outgoing light paths are horizontal and vertical lines, and if you transform to the [second](http://yukterez.net/f/einstein.equations/files/10.html#1) form the ingoing or outgoing ones will have ±45°.

With Schwarzschild you could just give your local set of observers the [squared](https://i.ibb.co/j3MLkGD/Unbenannt.png) escape velocity like you give them the regular one in [raindrop](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714074/schwarzschild-metric-in-terms-of-a-falling-observers-coordinates/714087#714087) coordinates in order to get the {ť, r} metric.

But in general it's easier to first [eliminate](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/772647/24093) the g<sub>rr</sub> term to get the horizontal and vertical worldlines in {u, r} and then take ť=u±r to get the ±45° photon worldlines on the {ť, r} spacetime [diagram](http://yukterez.net/f/einstein.equations/files/schwarzschild.raumzeitdiagramme.html#11).